# Find a users position on a ordered SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to use the SQL ORDER BY function and then find where a user is on the sorted list as a number

My columns are name and score I want to order by score and then find the users position on the table

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: no no no no no no and no

Comment: you can try this example data, what output do you want? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

Comment: So you want to generate row numbers for your result rows? (Then use juergen d's query.)

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, score, 
       @rank := @rank + 1 as rank
from your_table
cross join (select @rank := 0) r
order by score desc
```

Comment: My columns are name and score I want to order by score and then find the users position on the table

Comment: "Name" and "Score" sorry

Comment: Well then use this query and adapt it. It is not that hard

Comment: How do I adapt it?

Comment: Try to understand the query and put in your real table and column names

Comment: I don't know what @rank means

Comment: It's a variable. You can read more about them here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

Comment: `rank` is actually the sequence number you want to get. You don't need to replace that. I updated the query

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.